# How do I spread out the points on the x-axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

The labels on the x-axis are unreadable now (they are names), I was wondering if there was a way to space them out more/make it possible to read them.

[my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPhqt.png)(i am using matplotlib on python)

This is my code:

```
 plt.scatter(directors_u, dir_avg_imdb)
  plt.show()
```

I tried changing the xlim but the x axis remains clustered together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust figure size using `plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))`. You can use `plt.tight_layout()`. Another option may be `plt.xticks(rotation=45)` rotating labels.